# How to show snippets of code in razor page

Tags: c#, html, css, razor, blazor

I'm building the documentation page of Xamarin app in Blazor and I've encountered a problem.
I'd like to show code snippets on the page using razor page. So far, I don't have that big problem with C# code, for example of App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
   }
```

For something like that - I don't have any problems. I can correctly style it as `<code>` tag, with CSS or with MudBlazor (which I'm also using). Also, IDE is not recognizing it as inside-code.
The problem however is when:

a) I'm trying to add XAML code / tags

b) I'm trying to add some C# methods from Xamarin and they include tags, for example:

`_container.Resolve<WebService> ...`

So the IDE is recognizing `<WebService>` as something inside Blazor app.

Of course, I was already trying with `<code>` blocks with no success. Is there any way to make it work? I really need to show those in documentation so I'm a the dead point right now.

Comment: Please show your failing example to https://blazorfiddle.com/ and I'll take a look. I just tried <code>@("_container.Resolve<WebService>")</code> and it's rendered properly.

Comment: @BaneBojanić Thanks, I tried it and worked for that specific example. However for XAML code snippet, it is not working. Here's fiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/npcpt230

Comment: is this okay? https://blazorfiddle.com/s/ju09qgj2

Comment: @BaneBojanić Seems fine but is there any solution If I would like to include it as totally same as from application? So basically as You have the style for: white-space: pre to include line breaks? I've found solution with using &lt; and &gt; as replacements but I'm wondering if there is a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes. I also added some `\r\n` and a `\t` to demonstrate formatting with `<pre>`

```
@page "/"
<pre>
    <code>@someString</code>
</pre>
@code {
      string someString = "<Application.Resources>\r\n\t<Color x:Key=\"PrimaryText\">#777777</Color><Application.Resources>";
}
```

[Fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/015yix5r)

Comment: That's just perfect. I've also found solution with replacing opening tags with &lt; sign and I was also able to successfully show it on page. However - I will use Your solution probably. Thank You!